# why do I get undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am currently making a game, and I have some problems. I used define to make some special cases. This is my define script.

```
def answerCorrect()
    puts "Correct! Let's proceed to the next question."
    points = points + 1
end

def answerWrong()
    puts "Oh no! That's wrong! Try again!"
    points = points - 2
    input = gets.chomp
end
```

And the special case is:

```
if input == "x"
    answerCorrect()
else
    answerWrong()
end
```

However, I get this error:

```
`answerCorrect': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: initialize `points` to zero.  `points = 0` prior to calling `answerCorrect()` or `answerWrong()`

Comment: @rudolph9 assuming he wants the same points score used on both methods your solution would set a fresh points variable each time.

Comment: @Brad yeah he needs to use an instance variable or something else persistent.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `points` variable is not shared across the two methods.

Consider using an instance variable to manage the point system, ie.

```
class AnswerEvaluator
    def initialize
        @points = 0
    end

    def answerCorrect()
        puts "Correct! Let's proceed to the next question."
        @points = @points + 1
    end

    def answerWrong()
        puts "Oh no! That's wrong! Try again!"
        @points = @points - 2
        input = gets.chomp
    end
end
```

You could expand on this by using an `attr_accessor` if you don't want to access the `@points` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the method does not know what "points" is. you probably need to make this an instance variable `@points`

Example:

```
class myGame

     def initialize
         @points = 0
     end

     def answerCorrect()
          puts "Correct! Let's proceed to the next question."
          @points = @points + 1
      end

      def answerWrong()
          puts "Oh no! That's wrong! Try again!"
          @points = @points - 2
          input = gets.chomp
      end
end
```